# Como alterar um valor de uma variavel dentro de um if em java?

Tags: java, escopo-de-variáveis

Criei uma classe abstrata chamada Jogador e criei também as subclasses de jogador.

Agora eu preciso criar um menu para o usuário escolher qual será o personagem que ele vai usar na batalha, mas eu não consigo criar uma nova variável dentro do `if` ou alterar uma variável já declarada do lado de fora.

```
Jogador Player2;

if (menu==1){Player2 = Ryu;}
else if (menu==2){Player2 = Blanka;}
else if (menu==3){Player2 = Zangief;}
else if (menu==4){Player2 = ChunLi;}
else if (menu==5){Player2 = Ken;}
```

Na situação acima ao tentar usar a variável Player2 o Eclipse diz que a variável ainda não foi inicializada.

```
if (menu==1){Jogador Player2 = new Ryu();}
else if (menu==2){Jogador Player2 = new Blanka();}
else if (menu==3){Jogador Player2 = new Zangief();}
else if (menu==4){Jogador Player2 = new ChunLi();}
else if (menu==5){Jogador Player2 = new Ken();}
```

Já na situação acima, não funciona por motivo óbvio, já que ela será encerrada assim que o if for finalizado.

Então, alguém com um pouco mais de conhecimento que eu, consegue me explicar uma solução para que eu consiga selecionar um dos personagens?

Comment: [`switch...case`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) cairia melhor do que esse tanto de `if`, mas como não é bem o problema da pergunta, fica a dica como comentário mesmo.

Comment: Se a resposta aceita realmente é a que solucionou o problema, então a pergunta estava errada. O erro apresentado indica outra coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade Saulo Vitor, acredito que o eclipse está reclamando por um motivo, o que aconteceria se o seu menu não fosse nenhuma das opções?

Sei que você deve estar limitando as opções com todas as existentes, mas o eclipse não sabe disso, então ele reclama.

```
Jogador Player2;

if (menu==1){Player2 = new Ryu();}
else if (menu==2){Player2 = new Blanka();}
else if (menu==3){Player2 = new Zangief();}
else if (menu==4){Player2 = new ChunLi();}
else if (menu==5){Player2 = new Ken();}
```

Vamos supor que o seu menu recebe o valor 6. O que aconteceria com o seu código?

Quando o valor fosse 6, ele não passaria por nenhuma das opções e quando você tentasse utilizar o Player2, você receberia um grande `NullPointerException`.

Para isso você tem duas opções:

```
Jogador Player2 = new Personagem();

if (menu==1){Player2 = new Ryu();}
else if (menu==2){Player2 = new Blanka();}
else if (menu==3){Player2 = new Zangief();}
else if (menu==4){Player2 = new ChunLi();}
else if (menu==5){Player2 = new Ken();}
```

Isso faria que a sua proxima ação fosse com um personagem generico caso a opção não estivesse lá.

Ou utilizar esse código, que faz mais sentido para mim:

```
Jogador Player2;

if (menu==1){Player2 = new Ryu();}
else if (menu==2){Player2 = new Blanka();}
else if (menu==3){Player2 = new Zangief();}
else if (menu==4){Player2 = new ChunLi();}
else {Player2 = new Ken();}
```

Assim você está deduzindo que se não é nenhum dos valores, ele com total certeza será 5 e assim a variável sempre será inicializada.

Answer (score 2):

Você quase acertou. É um meio termo entre as duas. Parece que a solução seria esta. Só não garanto porque não tenho todo o contexto. É possível que tenha uma forma até melhor de fazer isto, mas não posso dizer só vendo este trecho.

```
Jogador Player2;
if (menu == 1) { Player2 = new Ryu(); }
else if (menu == 2) { Player2 = new Blanka(); }
else if (menu == 3) { Player2 = new Zangief(); }
else if (menu == 4) { Player2 = new ChunLi(); }
else if (menu == 5) { Player2 = new Ken(); }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/ChangeValue.java).

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece pois você está tentando atribuir um tipo sem instancia-lo.

Declare a variável fora e crie uma instância dentro da condição.

```
Jogador Player2;

if (menu == 1) { 
    Player2 = new Ryu; 
} else if (menu == 2) {
    Player2 = new Blanka;
} else if (menu == 3) {
    Player2 = new Zangief;
} else if (menu == 4) {
    Player2 = new ChunLi;
} else if (menu == 5){
    Player2 = new Ken;
}
```